# Bigquery SQL need advise and guidance please

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So i am still getting to grips with writing some more advanced queries and just seem to be hitting a brick wall. I have 3 tables where i would like to basically merge 3 columns into one list (distinct ids), for which i have unioned. Then I was using that to left join back to the original 3 tables. Am I completely off the mark with what i want? It is taking such a long time to run i figured im doing something wrong.

```
  with EDITED_MTE as (
  select
  
  (Case when board not like'Vee%' then device 
    when board like 'Vee%' then board
    when board is null then NULL else board end) as newid
    from `confluent.export_mte`
  group by newid)
  
  select distinct (MachineID),
  
  from(
  (select 
  DISTINCT(device) as MachineID
  from `confluent.export_workout` w)
  Union all
  (select 
  DISTINCT(deviceID) as MachineID
  from `confluent.export_fault` f)
  Union all
  (select 
  DISTINCT(newid) as MachineID
  from EDITED_MTE))
  
  left join `confluent.export_workout` w
  on MachineID=w.device
  left join `confluent.export_mte` m 
  on MachineID=m.board or MachineID=m.device
  left join `confluent.export_fault` f
  on MachineID=f.deviceId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query expresses what you're trying to do (you have some excess brackets that make it a little hard to read):

```
with EDITED_MTE as (
select distinct 
    Case when board not like'Vee%' then device 
        when board like 'Vee%' then board
        when board is null then NULL else board 
    end as newid
from `confluent.export_mte`
group by newid
), _union as (
   select DISTINCT device as MachineID
   from `confluent.export_workout`
   Union all
   select DISTINCT deviceID as MachineID
   from `confluent.export_fault`
   Union all
   select newid as MachineID
   from EDITED_MTE
)
select * --fyi: coalesce(m.field, m2.field) as field, etc 
from _union u
left join `confluent.export_workout` w on u.MachineID=w.device
left join `confluent.export_mte` m on u.MachineID=m.board
left join `confluent.export_mte` m2 on u.MachineID=m2.device
left join `confluent.export_fault` f on u.MachineID=f.deviceId
```

In my experience BigQuery doesn't like "OR" conditions when joining large tables and will often run for hours consuming ridiculous slot time. To avoid this you can simply join on the table twice and use coalesce to keep those fields the same... hope this helps.